# Doing a POST on Twitter's statuses/update resource using RestKit

Tags: ios, twitter, restkit, twitter-oauth

I am trying to post a tweet using RestKit but repeatedly get a 401 back ("message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32).

```
RKObjectManager *twitterObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:@"https://api.twitter.com"];

twitterObjectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth1;

twitterObjectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerKey = @"abc";
twitterObjectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerSecret = @"xyz";
twitterObjectManager.client.OAuth1AccessToken = @"lmn";
twitterObjectManager.client.OAuth1AccessTokenSecret = @"qrs";

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Make it work" forKey:@"status"];

[twitterObjectManager.client post:@"/1.1/statuses/update.json" params:parameters delegate:self];
```

The same oAuth keys work when reading statuses using GET from statuses/user_timeline.

Is there anything else which needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for twitter, trying to use API `version 1`, `NOT 1.1`

Comment: I tried with version 1 and am getting this error now - "error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth.","request":"\/statuses\/update.json"  PS - OAuth keys being used by me are the ones that Twitter has generated for my app.